# How to detect whether MainActivity was launched by the app starting, or by an intent by another activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

So I'm using Java in Android Studio and have come across a problem.

Essentially I have a value in my MainActivity, and when the user is in the EditActivity, they can edit this value. I do this by using putExtra for myValue when transferring from the MainActivity to the EditActivity, and when transferring back, the newly updated variable is named myNewValue. Essentially what I want is:

```
if(MainActivity is started via app launching){
    textView.setText(myValue)
}else if(MainActivity is started via intent from EditActivity){
    textView.setText(myNewValue)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **First Screen (splash screen)** . start your intent like this

```
intent.putextra("check_this","mainactivity");
intent.putextra(""your_value","abcd");
```

in your **EditActivity**.

```
intent.putextra("check_this","editactivity");
intent.putextra(""your_new_value","abcdefg");
```

So in your **CurrentScreen**.

```
Bundle b = getIntent.getExtra();

if(b.getString("check_this").equals("mainactivity")){
textView.setText(myValue). // this screen is opened from splash
}else{
 textView.setText(myNewValue). // this is from editactivity
}
```